# Java - check if a string is a subset of another string

Tags: java, string, substring, subset

I am trying to implement function, that checks if a String is a subset of another.

For example, "lig" is a subset of "light".

"gil" is also a subset of "light".

But "liig" is not a subset of "light".

I have tried everything, for loop, nested for loop, if, else...

I will appreciate your help of this one! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `if("light".contains("lig")) {//...}`

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by subset? Do you mean that the string s1 is subset of s2 if the string s1 can be created by the characters of string s2. Do the string s2 should have the characters in the same order as string s1 ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I mean that the letters of the first string, must also be in the second string, while the order doesn't matter. I have created a function that counts the number of times a character appears in a string, and tried to use it too, with no luck.

Comment: Are you familiar with Maps? If yes create a mapping which will count how many repetitions of characters exist in each string like `abbc` -> a:1 b:2 c:1 and then do the same for other string like `ba` a:1 b:1. Now you just need to check if letter from "subset" exist if map representing "superset" and doesn't exceed amount in superset.

Comment: @Pshemo Unfortunately not... I tried using indexOf() and contains() also...

Comment: Do you know that `char`s are just numbers which represents indexes of character/symbol in *Unicode Table*? We can use that fact to convert each char to its index by *casting* it to `int`, like `int unicodeIndex = (char)'a';` which will convert `'a'` to its index `97`. With this you can use array and create mapping `unicodeIndex` -> `amount of occurrences`.

Comment: Yes that is great thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a `Hashmap` and some simple operations described in the comments:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isSubset("light", "lig"));
        System.out.println(isSubset("light", "gil"));
        System.out.println(isSubset("light", "liig"));
    }
    private static boolean isSubset(String str, String sub) {
        // change strings to lower case
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        sub = sub.toLowerCase();
        // initialze hashmap to store character frequencies in substring
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        // iterate over the substring and store number of occurrences per character
        for(char c : sub.toCharArray()) {
            Integer count = map.get(c);
            map.put(c, count!=null ? count+1 : 1);
        }
        // iterate over the original string and decrement the count of each character present in the map
        for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            Integer count = map.get(c);
            if(count!=null)
                map.put(c, count-1);
        }
        // check if all characters count has reached to zero, i.e., present in the string
        for(int count : map.values())
            if(count != 0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately I do not familiar with StringBuilder, or toString or Reverse. I am trying to use simple methods.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I think that I will understand what you did here in a couple of weeks, so I will return to read it again once I do.